# UWP Extended Splash Screen Not Closing

Tags: uwp

I am a little rusty on the UWP front.
I got hold of the UWP Van Arsdel Inventory sample app that was used with one of the Microsoft Build events.
I wanted to do use that as a reference for a small reporting app I needed to create.
I got stuck however on the extended splash screen.
It wont closed when I navigate to the MainShellView

The extended splash is opened from the App.xaml.cs

```
 var activationInfo = ActivationService.GetActivationInfo(e);

        var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame == null)
        {
            var loadState = (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
            var extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(e, loadState);
            Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
        else
        {
            var navigationService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetService<INavigationService>();
            await navigationService.CreateNewViewAsync(activationInfo.EntryViewModel, activationInfo.EntryArgs);
        }
```

And then in the extended splash screen I want to navigation to the main shell view

```
  _rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainShellView));
        Window.Current.Content = _rootFrame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

But it never closes

Comment: Can you share a code sample that could reproudce this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work.
But unfortunately I cannot say what has changed.
I think I might have had an incorrect refeence to something or the wrong Navigation service class in my project.
But looking at the code It looks identical.
Anyhow I created a public repo if someone wants a reference

https://nelludwig.visualstudio.com/UWPLOBSample/_git/UWPLOBSample.Client